# This FORTRAN code shouldn't compile. Is there a reason why it does?

Tags: compilation, fortran, fortran90, gfortran

The following code compiles, but I do not think that it should. As you can see, the output is garbage.

This is a minimal failing example of something that bit me hard in a large project I work on.

My question is - why does the compiler not complain? Is this a compiler limitation, or is this somehow "expected behaviour", and I've missed something?

I'm using gfortran 4.6.3.

```
module dataModule
    integer :: datum1 = int(1)
    integer :: datum2 = int(2)    
end module dataModule

program moduleTest
    use dataModule, only: datum1

    write(*,*) "datum 1 is", datum1
    write(*,*) "datum 2 is", datum2

end program moduleTest
```

Example output:

```
datum 1 is           1
datum 2 is  4.58322689E-41
```

Comment: You've missed `implicit none`.  Without it the code is quite valid and the output is allowed.

Comment: oldest trick in the book :)

Comment: Ahh of course! Thanks guys. It's actually worse than that, the module I was editing in the (very old!) code has
    IMPLICIT REAL*8 (a-h,o-z)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is at fault, not the compiler.  *If* `datum2` were use associated despite the `only` clause and *if* the explicit initialization of `datum2` were ignored, then yes, that would be a naughty compiler.

The answer is much more mundane, though.

`datum2` is not use associated: in the absence of `implicit none` it is an implicitly typed variable in the main program.  The "garbage" comes from the fact that it is not defined, by initialization or assignment, before its value is referenced and that it's implicitly (default) real.  The compiler isn't required to detect this mistake at compile (or run) time.

Comment: What is this, @francescalus? Coming back for your "accepted answer" internet points many months after answering in a comment? Oh go on then ;)

What I've learned is that one of the pitfalls of working with ancient Fortran code is that it doesn't have any `implicit none`s in it, and life is too short to pick through and properly type all the variables. So I re-wrote it all in C++.

Comment: The strange part is I had this question open in a tab in my browser for six months.  So, potentially tidying the "unanswered" part of the internet and my desktop ;).